# What are the rules wrt. sig figs when multiplying or dividing a number with an uncertainty and an exact number?

Tags: error-propagation, significant-figures

The answer sheet for my math book is full of errors and the book does not explain this concept at all. According to it :

(28,3 ± 0,05) x 4 = 113,2 ± 0,2

So one sig fig is added to the value and one is removed from the uncertainty.

(28,3 ± 0,05) ÷ 4 = 7,075 ± 0,0125 rounded to 7,08 ± 0,01

Here the number of sig figs for both the value and the uncertainty is maintained, but the value is rounded to one more decimal place.

I am confused as to what the rules are supposed to be here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The rule is the distributive property. Try not to think about rules and think instead of what is happening mathematically. If your initial value is likely in the set $[28.25, 28.35]$ then after multiplying by $4$ it is just as likely in the set $[113.0, 113.4]$. That is, $4 \cdot [28.25, 28.35] = [113.0, 113.4]$. The rules about the numbers of significant figures in error propagation are just rules of thumb that help you through these kinds of calculations, but you shouldn't lose sight of what is actually going on mathematically.